# Programming language R: Create a function. This Function converts one matrix to another matrix such that every odd number are 3 times of that number

Tags: r

[1 2] -->[3    2]
[3 5] -->[9 15]

Please help me solve it. The above is an example(both are 2*2 matrices)

Comment: Show us some of your code. What have you tried and what did not work?

Comment: getting only errors...  > s=function(mata){
 if(mata %% 2 == 0){replace mata, c(mata), c(3*mata)}
  Error: unexpected symbol in:
"if(mata %% 2 == 0){
replace mata"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of ways to do this :

```
thrice_matrix1 <- function(mat) {
  inds <- mat %% 2 == 1
  mat[inds] <- mat[inds] * 3
  return(mat)
}

mat <- matrix(1:9, 3)
thrice_matrix1(mat)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    3    4   21
#[2,]    2   15    8
#[3,]    9    6   27
```

---

Other variations could be :

```
thrice_matrix2 <- function(mat) {
   c(1, 3)[(mat %% 2 == 1) + 1] * mat
}
```

and

```
thrice_matrix3 <- function(mat) {
  ifelse(mat %% 2 == 1, mat * 3, mat)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was able to understand how the third code worked(thrice_matrix3) :) Wondering why I wasn't able to think of this...Thank you very much for helping me

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO,
I like to use support functions and then apply the logic in the matrix

```r
example_1 <- matrix(1:2)
example_2 <- matrix(c(3,5))
example_3 <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow = 2)
is_odd_triple <- function(x) {
  ifelse(x %% 2 == 1,x*3,x)
}

is_odd_triple(1:10)
#>  [1]  3  2  9  4 15  6 21  8 27 10

apply(example_1, 1, is_odd_triple)
#> [1] 3 2
apply(example_2, 1, is_odd_triple)
#> [1]  9 15
apply(example_3, 1, is_odd_triple)
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    3    2
#> [2,]    9    4
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot! (code is a little complex :D for my level of understanding)